# Tile Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, aster

The below code has written for ASTER radiometric correction in Google Earth Engine but in visualization step, returns this error:
[image]

code link:https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ccaaaa0e9ce68bdf80b8056be5d057d

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table)
 
var ast = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003")
.filterDate('2000-01-01','2020-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,9,'month'))
.select('B0[4-9]')
.map(function(img){
  
  var gain4 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B04').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04')));
  var gain5 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B05').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B05')));
  var gain6 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B06').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B06')));
  var gain7 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B07').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B07')));
  var gain8 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B08').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B08')));
  var gain9 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B08').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B09')));
  
  
  var b4 = img.select('B04').multiply(gain4).clip(table);
  var b5 = img.select('B05').multiply(gain5).clip(table);
  var b6 = img.select('B06').multiply(gain6).clip(table);
  var b7 = img.select('B07').multiply(gain7).clip(table);
  var b8 = img.select('B08').multiply(gain8).clip(table);
  var b9 = img.select('B09').multiply(gain9).clip(table);
  
  
  var stack = ee.Image.cat([b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9]);
  return stack
}).median();


print(ast);

Map.addLayer(ast)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every image in the images you've selected has the properties `GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04` and so on. For example, `ASTER/AST_L1T_003/20100709070749` has only

```
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B01: 0.676
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B02: 0.708
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B10: 0.006822
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B11: 0.00678
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B12: 0.00659
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B13: 0.005693
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B14: 0.005225
GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B3N: 0.862
```

Thus, `.get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04')` returns null, and your image calculation fails because null is not a valid value for a constant image.

You can add a filter on the image collection to ensure those properties are present:

```
.filter(ee.Filter.notNull([
  'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04',
  'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B05',
  'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B06',
  'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B07',
  'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B08',
  'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B09',
]))
```

---

I noticed some other improvements that could be made to your code.

```
  var gain4 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.select('B04').get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04')));
```

Here, the `.select('B04')` does nothing (since you're getting a property, and properties are independent of bands). Also, there are variants of `.get()` that eliminate needing to write `ee.Number`:

```
  var gain4 = ee.Image(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04'));
```

But this can be even simpler: it isn't necessary to write `ee.Image(constant)` in many cases; you can write a number and it will be converted to an image.

```
  var b4 = img.select('B04').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04')).clip(table);
```

Finally, it is unnecessarily inefficient to `.clip(table)` the individual images rather than the result, and when you are clipping to a table/collection you should use the more efficient `.clipToCollection(table)` (though this doesn't matter since you only have one feature).

```
.map(function(img){
  ...
}).median().clipToCollection(table);
```

Putting it all together:

```
var ast = ee.ImageCollection("ASTER/AST_L1T_003")
  .filterDate('2000-01-01','2020-01-01')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,9,'month'))
  .select('B0[4-9]')
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull([
    'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04',
    'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B05',
    'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B06',
    'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B07',
    'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B08',
    'GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B09',
  ]))
  .map(function(img){
    return ee.Image.cat([
      img.select('B04').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B04')),
      img.select('B05').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B05')),
      img.select('B06').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B06')),
      img.select('B07').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B07')),
      img.select('B08').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B08')),
      img.select('B09').multiply(img.getNumber('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B09')),
    ]);
  })
  .median()
  .clipToCollection(table);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ba97a7c2009def6043c614c5aeae4f7

Comment: It works as well as your comments.